# How to add active class to dynamic menu?

Tags: php, mysql

please help. How can I add active class to the dynamic menu? I use While for my menu list, but I cannot understand how to add it to active class. I kindly ask for your consult and advice. Thanks in advance.

[picture of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heiAW.jpg)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
<?php 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id ASC";
    $menuQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);            
     ?>


    <?php
    while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuQuery)): 
       echo ' 
     <li><a href="'.$menu['menu'].'" class=\'active\'>'.$menu["menu_title"].'</a></li>' ?>     
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong eith the above code? It does reference the class property...

Comment: Depends on how you get your current active page. You could simply check if the current url is the same as `$menu['menu']`, depends again on its content.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my inquiry. The idea you gave me was quite helpful, and I was able to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved!
I'll leave this code in hopes of it helping somebody else in need.

```
<?php $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
<?php 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id ASC";
    $menuQuery = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);   
     ?>


    <?php
    while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuQuery)): 
        if($link == $menu['menu']){
        $active = 'class=\'active\'';
        }
        ?>

    <li  <?php if($link == $menu['menu']){  echo $active; } ?> > <a href="<?=$menu['menu'];?>" ><?=$menu["menu_title"];?></a></li> 
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```